# How can one properly declare char8_t for diacritical letters?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, utf-8, utf, c++20

I attempt to initialise some **diacritical Latin letters** using the new `char8_t` type:

```
constexpr char8_t french_letter_A_1 = 'À';//does not function properly
```

However, Visual Studio 2019 suggests me the following **“character represented by universal-character-name "\u(the name)" cannot be represented in the current code page”**, and the character cannot be properly displayed; If I try to explicitly declare the character as a `u8` one, like:

```
constexpr char8_t french_letter_A_2 = u8'Â';//has error
```

It even throws an error **" a UTF-8 character literal value cannot occupy more than one code unit"**; but non-diacritical letters can be successfully interpreted as a UTF-8 one:

```
constexpr char8_t french_letter_A_0 = u8'A';//but ASCII letters are fine
```

I am wondering how can I properly declare a UTF-8 character with **Visual C++**... or I misunderstand the concept of `char8_t`, and should rather use something else instead?

Edit: I have comprehended that `char8_t` does not support those non-ASCII characters. What character type should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char8_t`, like `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`, has a size of 1 byte.  On most platforms (but not all!), that means it is an 8-bit type only capable of holding 256 discrete values.  Unicode 12.1 defines 137,994 characters.  Clearly, they can't all fit in a single `char8_t` value!

The C and C++ "character" types are, regrettably, poorly named.  If we were designing a new language with modern terminology, we would name them some variation of `code_unit` as that better reflects how they are actually used.  `char32_t` is the only character type that is currently guaranteed to be able to hold a code point value for every character in its associated character set (the C and C++ standards claim that `wchar_t` can too, but that contradicts existing practice).

Looking at your example, À is U+00C0 {LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE} (or is it actually A U+0041 {LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A} followed by  ̀ U+0300 {COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT}?  Unicode is tricky that way).  The UTF-8 encoding of U+00C0 is 0xC3 0x80.  What value should `french_letter_A_1` hold?  It can't hold both code unit values.  And if the value were to be the code point, then we're either in the situation that only 256 characters can be (portably) supported or, worse, that sometimes values of `char8_t` are code points and sometimes they are code units.

The reality is that C and C++ character literals are limited to just a few more characters than are in the [basic source character set](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.charset#1).  That is sufficient if one is writing an English-only application.  But for modern applications, character literals have limited use.

As Nicol already stated, working with most characters outside the basic source character set requires doing real text processing on strings.  Unfortunately, the C and C++ standards do not provide much help there.  That is something that [SG16](https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16) is working to improve.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is an encoding for Unicode codepoints. In UTF-8, a codepoint is broken down into one or more "octets" (8-bit words) called UTF-8 code units. The C++20 type that represents a UTF-8 code unit is `char8_t`.

A single `char8_t` is only one UTF-8 code unit. Therefore, it can only represent a Unicode codepoint whose UTF-8 encoding only takes up 1 code unit. Visual Studio is telling you that the "character" you are trying to store in a `char8_t` requires more than 1 code unit and therefore cannot be stored in such a type. The only Unicode code points that UTF-8 encodes in a single code unit are the ASCII code points.

When dealing with UTF-8 (or any Unicode encoding that isn't UTF-32 for that matter), you do not deal in "characters"; you deal in *strings*: contiguous sequences of code units. Anytime you want to deal with UTF-8, you should be using some kind of `char8_t`-based string type.

Comment: So what character type should I use for non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @Emancipatrix: As I said: "When dealing with UTF-8, you do not deal in "characters"; you deal in strings ... you should be using some kind of char8_t-based string type." Or to put it another way, there is no such thing as a UTF-8 "character" in the sense that you mean it.

Comment: So shall I use `wchar` for those accented letters? If so, shall I declare them like `L'À'` or something similar? If not, which is the character type that best represents them?

Comment: @Emancipatrix: ... I don't know how I could possibly make things clearer. ***Do not use characters!*** Use *strings*. When dealing with any Unicode encoding, you should not be dealing with any kind of fixed-sized "character". And no, `wchar_t` or `char16_t` doesn't help because many Unicode codepoints of them won't fit in one 16-bit word. Just stop trying to have characters. And there are ways of writing an accented letter that require multiple Unicode codepoints. `u8"À"` is what you should be creating, using, and manipulating.

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment from someone-who's-not-Nicol-Bolas to agree that Nicol is exactly correct. If you're doing Unicode, you're doing strings, by definition. There is no such thing as "a Unicode character." There are only strings. I say this as the author of [this blog post](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/02/03/on-teaching-unicode/) where I ask rhetorically, "What’s the first char of “ﷻ”? What’s the first char of “ﬃ”? What’s the first char of “”? What’s the first char of “”? What’s the first char of “‍”?" These questions cannot be answered, only unasked.